# regex for {productName}-{version}-{X}-of-{Y}.EXE in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi I need regular expression to match the following format in c#

{productName}-{version}-{X}-of-{Y}.EXE

Example

AttDts-14.0.0.1-1-of-3.EXE

AttDts-14.0.0.1-2-of-3.EXE

AttDts-14.0.0.1-3-of-3.EXE

If I have package names as mentioned above in example, can single expression match the whole package?

Thanks,
Twinkle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex. This should work according to your specification.

```
Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"/\w+-(?:\d+\.){3}\d+-\d+-of-\d+.EXE/",
                                                   RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I am going to accept this answer. Just one more request is this possible to enforce rules through expression. What I means to say is here the package name is AttDts-14.0.0.1-3-of-3.EXE, i.e 1 of 3, 2 of 3 and 3 of 3 but if somebody mistakenly put 4 of 2 or 9 of 3 it shouldn't match, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use this: @"/\w+-(?:\d+\.){3}\d+-[1|2|3|4]-of-[1|2|3|4].EXE/" ...This regex will check for x-of-y where 1<=x,y<5 with no relation between x and y. If you want to enforce x<y then I think regex will get complex. In that case you would want to move complex validation rules into the actual code by parsing and validating individual parts of the subject string.

Comment: if I am using the same expression to get the groups but only getting one group. I have used your expression and changed to get groups (\w+)-((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)-(\d+)-of-(\d+).exe Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is right. You can capture the groups as follows:
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\w+)-((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)-(\d+)-of-(\d+).EXE", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string resultString = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups[1].Value;
This expression captures the first group and places it in resultString. Regex.IsMatch just checks if there is a match, you have to use the above code to actually capture the group.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try this expression:

```
([^\-]+)\-((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\-(\d+)\-of\-(\d+)\.exe
```

**Edit - Regular Expression**

Then you can implement a method with this pattern:

```
static bool isValidPackageName(string packageName)
{
    String pattern = @"([^\-]+)\-((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\-(\d+)\-of\-(\d+)\.exe";
    return Regex.Match(packageName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
}
```

**Edit - Improved Method**

By the way, if you don't need to validate for each item on the string (productName, version, x, y) you could just simply do the following:

```
String input = "AttDts-14.0.0.1-1-of-3.EXE";
String pattern = @"([^\-]+)(?=[\-.])";

Regex regularExpression = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matchCollection = regularExpression.Matches(input);

if (matchCollection.Count > 0)
{
    int groupPosition = 0;
    foreach (var group in matchCollection)
    {
        switch (groupPosition)
        {
            // {productName}
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", group);
                break;
            // {version}
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", group);
                break;
            // {X}
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("X: {0}", group);
                break;
            // of
            case 3:
                break;
            // {Y}
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Y: {0}", group);
                break;

        }
        ++groupPosition;
    }
}
```

**Edit - Split**

Or you can just simply avoid using regular expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String input = "AttDts-14.0.0.1-1-of-3.EXE";
    String[] splits = input.Split(new char[] { '-' });

    int splitCounter = 0;
    foreach (var split in splits)
    {
        switch (splitCounter)
        {
            case 0:
                var productName = split;
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", productName);

                break;

            case 1:
                var version = split;
                Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", version);

                break;

            case 2:
                var x = split;
                Console.WriteLine("X: {0}", x);

                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:
                var y = split.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];
                Console.WriteLine("Y: {0}", y);
                break;
        }
        ++splitCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding option 2, I'm a big fan of named capture groups... For example: `@"(?<Name>[^\-]+)\-(?<Version>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)\-(?<X>\d+)\-of\-(?<Y>\d+)\.exe"`. Then you can use `match.Groups["Name"]` and be more resilient to changes to your search pattern.